# html input ng-directive won't update value on change

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, autocomplete, undefined-behavior

First let me explain the context before saying what the problem is, I have the following function in a angularjs controller:

```
$scope.autocomplete = function(input, lista) {

        var currentFocus;

        input.addEventListener("input", function (e) {
            var a, b, i, val = this.value;
            closeAllLists();
            if (!val) { return false; }
            currentFocus = -1;

            a = document.createElement("DIV");
            a.setAttribute("id", this.id + "autocomplete-list");
            a.setAttribute("class", "autocomplete-items");

            this.parentNode.appendChild(a);
            for (i = 0; i < lista.length; i++) {
                var nomeItem = lista[i].nome;
                var codigoItem = lista[i].codigo;

                var itemLista = nomeItem.toUpperCase();
                var inputTexto = val.toUpperCase();
                if (itemLista.includes(inputTexto)) {

                    b = document.createElement("DIV");

                    var quantidadeDeLetras = 0;
                    var inicio = "", meio = "", fim = "", contarLetras = "";
                    for (var contador = 0; contador < nomeItem.length; contador++) {
                        var parteNome = nomeItem.substr(contador, val.length);
                        if (contador > 0) {
                            inicio = nomeItem.substr(0, contador);
                        }
                        if (parteNome.toUpperCase() == val.toUpperCase()) {
                            meio = "<strong>" + parteNome + "</strong>";
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    contarLetras = inicio + val;
                    quantidadeDeLetras = contarLetras.length;
                    fim = nomeItem.substr(quantidadeDeLetras);
                    b.innerHTML = inicio + meio + fim;

                    b.innerHTML += "<input type='hidden' name='" + codigoItem + "' value='" + nomeItem + "'>";

                    b.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
                        input.value = this.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;
                        $scope.RespostaAutocomplete(this.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].name);

                        closeAllLists();
                    });
                    a.appendChild(b);
                }
            }
        });

        input.addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {
            var x = document.getElementById(this.id + "autocomplete-list");
            if (x) x = x.getElementsByTagName("div");
            if (e.keyCode == 40) {
                currentFocus++;
                addActive(x);
            } else if (e.keyCode == 38) { //up

                currentFocus--;
                addActive(x);
            } else if (e.keyCode == 13) {

                e.preventDefault();
                if (currentFocus > -1) {
                    if (x) x[currentFocus].click();
                }
            }
        });
        function addActive(x) {
            if (!x) return false;
            removeActive(x);
            if (currentFocus >= x.length) currentFocus = 0;
            if (currentFocus < 0) currentFocus = (x.length - 1);
            x[currentFocus].classList.add("autocomplete-active");
        }
        function removeActive(x) {
            for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
                x[i].classList.remove("autocomplete-active");
            }
        }
        function closeAllLists(elmnt) {
            var x = document.getElementsByClassName("autocomplete-items");
            for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
                if (elmnt != x[i] && elmnt != input) {
                    x[i].parentNode.removeChild(x[i]);
                }
            }
        }
        document.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
            closeAllLists(e.target);
        });
    }
```

It takes an html input and a object list with name and id as parameters to create a autocomplete input, it works without problems, I call it like this:

```
$scope.autocomplete(document.getElementById("autocompleteInput"), $scope.projetos);
```

And when some item is selected I retrieve the id calling a function called RespostaAutoComplete sending the information through a hidden input, this is the function that retrieves the information:

```
 $scope.RespostaAutocomplete = function (codigo) {
        //*do stuff here*
    };
```

Now, the "codigo" parameters is the id from the list previously sent to the function, everything  works fine, if I work with that variable only in my controller, there is no problem, but if I load any information into an scope bounded with an ng-directive, html won't ever show it, example:

```
$scope.RespostaAutocomplete = function (codigo) {
        $scope.idYouJustSelected = codigo;
    };
```

And on html i have an input like this:

```
<input class="form-control " id="test" type="text" ng-model="idYouJustSelected" >
```

The scope variable get the id without problems, and I tested if they are undefined after that fuction but it works, it doesn't show any kind of error or weird behavior on inspect, but the input just won't show the information in the scope if it was loaded ONLY in the function after the autocomplete input is selected, anywhere else works perfectly.
And a weird behavior is, if, in that same function where the updated information is not shown in the html input have a GET method for any reason, literally just a empty get method to any random service for any purpose, without even using the response, the html input updates the information normally, like:

```
$scope.RespostaAutocomplete = function (codigo) {
         $http.get(__ambiente.apiUrl + 'randomservice')
           .then (
                function (resposta) {
                },
                function (error) {
                });
        $scope.idYouJustSelected = codigo;
    };
```

Then, for some reason, it works, I have no idea what is going on...

Comment: AngularJS modifies the normal JavaScript flow by providing its own event processing loop. This splits the JavaScript into classical and AngularJS execution context. Only operations which are applied in the AngularJS execution context will benefit from AngularJS data-binding, exception handling, property watching, etc. Read [AngularJS Developer Guide - 
Integration with the browser event loop](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope#integration-with-the-browser-event-loop).

Comment: The `.then` method of a $http promise initiates an AngularJS framework digest cycle. It is not wise to do DOM manipulation in an AngularJS controller. DOM manipulation should be done in directives.

Comment: thanks,  that's very helpful, btw I solved the problem yesterday by surrouding my retrieving funtion with $apply, was that a good thing to do, or there is a better aproach?

Comment: Read [AngularJS Developer Guide - Creating Custom Directives](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) and [AngularJS jqLite API reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element#angularjs-s-jqlite). Adding event listeners and creating DOM are better done inside a directive using the built-in jQuery API. This will aviod conflict with DOM manipulation by core AngularJS directives.

Comment: OK great, thanks so much for your help